# SharePoint Group Site Collections and other type of Site Collections

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, office-365-groups, communication-site

When I go to my SharePoint onliine and on top left corner select app-launcher and choose SharePoint, I can see several site collections some of them are associated to SharePoint Groups and some of them are communication sites. the url for all of them is something like
`https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/MyO365Group/SitePages/Home.aspx`
or
`https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/MyCommunicationSite/SitePages/Home.aspx`

**Question 1:** Are these Site collections or sites and what is differents between them? because when I browse to them thay have different layout and navigation.

**Question 2:** When I go to admin portal `https://portal.office.com/adminportal` and choose SharePoint under Admin Centers, I can see all my Site Collections that I created long time ago, but I cannot find none of above Site Collections (Communication and Group site collections), What is differents between these Site collections and those? where are those site collections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Both are site collections.

- To share & collaborate with the team, you can create modern Team Site Collection. When ever you create Office 365 group, a new SharePoint Site Collection will be created using Modern "Team" site template. This is vice versa.
- To share with the entire organization, you can use Communication Site Collection.

Based on their purpose, Microsoft provided different layouts for each templates.

Question 2: You can't see the modern SiteCollections from the old SharePoint Admin center.

- New SharePoint Admin center has the feature to view all the Site Collections including classic template sites & Modern template sites. New Admin center is enabled for First Release Users.
- All sites can be view able in below link. And this link available for first release users.

https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/siteManagement